# Synchronization of WASAPI Audio Devices

Tags: audio, wasapi

Is there a way with WASAPI to determine if two devices (an input and an output device) are both synced to the same underlying clock source?

In all the examples I've seen input and output devices are handled separately - typically a different thread or event handle is used for each and I've not seen any discussion about how to keep two devices in sync (or how to handle the devices going out of sync).

For my app I basically need to do real-time input to output processing where each audio cycle I get a certain number of incoming samples and I send the same number of output samples.  ie: I need one triggering event for the audio cycle that will be correct for both devices - not separate events for each device.

I also need to understand how this works in both exclusive and shared modes.  For exclusive I guess this will come down to finding if devices have a common clock source.  For shared mode some information on what Windows guarantees about synchronization of devices would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IAudioClock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nn-audioclient-iaudioclock) API to detect drift of a given audio client, relative to QPC; if two endpoints share a clock, their drift relative to QPC will be identical (that is, they will have zero drift relative to each other.)

You can use the [IAudioClockAdjustment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nn-audioclient-iaudioclockadjustment) API to adjust for drift that you can detect. For example, you could correct both sides for drift relative to QPC; you could correct either side for drift relative to the other; or you could split the difference and correct both sides to the mean.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  That's an interesting idea, but seems a complicated thing to have to do just to determine if two devices have the same clock source.  ie: if I'm trying to build a UI that presents endpoints with the same clock source then having to start and monitor different combinations of devices seems a bit of a reach.  Basically it sounds like there's no easy way to do real time input to output streaming with WASAPI, which is unfortunate. :(